# Function chaining

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am struggling to understand how this JavaScript code work. I am learning JS, and not exposed to a dynamic, functional language before. So, I visualize function calls in bit procedural, hierarchical order. With d3.js, one can draw svg elements as explained [here](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/using-your-data/)

---

```
var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];

d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text("New paragraph!");
```

Let’s change the last line:

```
.text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Check out what the new code does on this demo page.

Whoa! We used our data to populate the contents of each paragraph, all thanks to the magic of the data() method. You see, when chaining methods together, anytime after you call data(), you can create an anonymous function that accepts d as input. The magical data() method ensures that d is set to the corresponding value in your original data set, given the current element at hand.

---

This magic, mentioned above is what I fail to understand. "d" is not a global variable, as if I change to another (c) name, it still works. So, the `data` method may be setting the value for the anonymous fn.

But, typically(with my limited reading) chaining is possible because the current function returns an object, on which the next method can be invoked. In the above case, how `data` method knows whether a text ("New paragraph!") is passed by the user, otherwise pass the data to the anonymous fn. The doubt is, the `text` method is down the line and `data()` is already executed. How the data is passed to the anonymous function?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging into d3.js [internals](http://alignedleft.com/content/15.tutorials/10.d3/d3/d3.js) shows the following result for `text` function:

```
d3_selectionPrototype.text = function(value) {
  return arguments.length < 1
      ? this.node().textContent : this.each(typeof value === "function"
      ? function() { var v = value.apply(this, arguments); this.textContent = v == null ? "" : v; } : value == null
      ? function() { this.textContent = ""; }
      : function() { this.textContent = value; });
};
```

In case the supplied argument is a function, the following code gets executed:

```
this.each(function() {
    var v = value.apply(this, arguments);  // executing function provided
    this.textContent = v == null ? "" : v;
});
```

Function `each` is declared as:

```
d3_selectionPrototype.each = function(callback) {
  for (var j = -1, m = this.length; ++j < m;) {
    for (var group = this[j], i = -1, n = group.length; ++i < n;) {
      var node = group[i];
      if (node) callback.call(node, node.__data__, i, j); // this is the line you are interested in
    }
  }
  return this;
};
```

so on each invocation it supplies an element from `this`. And, getting down to it, `this` is populated by `data` function invocation.

Comment: you nailed it. thank you very much. data function store the individual values to __data__ https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data. One quick qn though, the anonymous fn takes only one argument, and through call it provides 4. How this work?

Comment: You are talking about `callback.call(node, node.__data__, i, j)`, right? First argument is the scope - `this` inside the callback, then goes the data, you are referring to it as `d`, then - the indices. For javascript it does not matter how many named arguments you are using - you could supply whatever number of arguments to the function. All the arguments are available using `arguments` variable. Named arguments are just a shortcut.
Btw, replace `function(d) { return d; }` with `function(d, i, j) { return d; }` and check it out yourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have never used d3 before, but this is what I understand.

`d` is the data object (I would call it `data` instead of `d` had set in the `data()` method.

So what does the `text()` method does? Will it will call the function and use it's output, something like this:

```
function text (callback) {
  var theText;
  if (typeof callback === "function") {
    theText = callback(dataset);
  } else {
    theText = callback;
  }
  // does something more
}
```

So, if callback is a function call it, and use its return value as text.

Then, what I'm guessing, is that if the function is an array, it will call the text method for each element in the array.

Something like this...

```
function text(callback) {
  var theText;
  if (typeof callback === "function") {
    theText = callback(dataset);
  } else {
    theText = callback;
  }
  if (theText instanceof Array) { // this is not the best way to check if an object is an array, I'll come back to this later. I'm sorry.
    for (var i=0, len=theText.length; i<len; i++) {
      text(theText[i]);
    }
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
  // do something more
}
```

please take into account that this would be a really simple version of what really happens.

If it's not clear enough please let me know.